# mysql.cpp compilation error in MATLAB

Tags: c++, mysql, database, matlab, connection

Hi Im trying to compile a c++ file viz. mysql.cpp for connecting Matlab to mysql database.
I used the same file before and was able to compile it without any issue but I had to re-install Matlab yesterday and when I tried compiling the file, I get many syntax errors although I have not made any changes in the cpp file.
For reference, the file was taken from here: -

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8663-mysql-database-connector

I get the following errors:-

```
Error mysql.cpp: 57  illegal initialization for parameter 'n'   
Error mysql.cpp: 98  syntax error; found 't' expecting ')'  
Error mysql.cpp: 98  skipping 't'  
Error mysql.cpp: 100  undeclared identifier 't'  
Warning mysql.cpp: 100   possible usage of t before definition  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ';'  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ';'  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ')'  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  skipping 'int'  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  undeclared identifier 'j'  
Warning mysql.cpp: 177  Statement has no effect  
Warning mysql.cpp: 177  unreachable code  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  syntax error; found ')' expecting ';'  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  illegal statement termination  
Error mysql.cpp: 177  skipping ')'   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ';'   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ';'  
Error mysql.cpp: 183  syntax error; found 'int' expecting ')'   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  skipping 'int' 
Error mysql.cpp: 183  undeclared identifier 'j'   
Warning mysql.cpp: 183  Statement has no effect   
Warning mysql.cpp: 183  unreachable code   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  syntax error; found ')' expecting ';'   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  illegal statement termination   
Error mysql.cpp: 183  skipping ')'   
Error mysql.cpp: 186  too many errors
```

I did the setup for mex using

```
mex -setup
```

and used the following command for compilation: -

```
mex -DWIN32 -I'D:\Softwares\MY SQL\mysql-5.6.12-win32\mysql-5.6.12-win32\include'
-L'D:\Softwares\MY SQL\mysql-5.6.12-win32\mysql-5.6.12-win32\lib' -llibmysql mysql.cpp
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try `mex -setup C++`?  It sure looks like the compiler that was called was a strictly `C` compiler - for example, `C` does not allow default arguments.  Do you have the **full** output of the `mex` command that includes the command-line that `mex` passed to Windows when it executed the build?

Comment: This is the last line of the error message I got:-           D:\MATLAB~2\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'mysql.cpp' failed. I think as you(@Dan Nissenbaum)said its trying to compile using C compiler. the list of compiler during mex -setup is only    Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in D:\MATLAB~2\sys\lcc

Comment: I guess i have to install c++ compiler as the `mex -setup C++` says  `D:\MATLAB~2\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'C++' not found.`

Comment: I installed Microsoft Sdk and was able to compile the file and got the mex file `mysql.mexw32` file but unable to connect to the database using the function as I get this error:- `Invalid MEX-file 'D:\MATLAB\mysql.mexw32':
The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Can you please physically look in the location `D:\MATLAB` and see if the `mysql.mexw32` file is there?

Comment: Yes, I checked that first up. Its there in the same location from where Im trying to run the function. I checked out some details about "module could not be found". Some .dll files are missing which is why the error is shown. I checked with Dependency Walker for the missing .dll files and got to know that LIBMEX.dll, LIBMX.dll and LIBMYSQL.dll are missing(or not created).

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this by Chuck Saunders:

Here's how I got this to work on Matlab R2015a installed on a 64 bit Windows 7 install. I started with no compiler and no SQL installed:

- Search for the "MySQL Community Installer", download it, then have it install the "full" option.
- Check Add/Remove programs to see if you have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable packages installed, BOTH the (x86) and the (x64) packages will cause the Windows SDK 7.1 install to fail.
- If you have them, search for the "Microsoft Fix It" utility. Run it, selecting "Uninstall", and use it to uninstall all of the VC++ 2010 redistributables.
- Download and install Windows SDK. If the install fails and you didn't bother to run the Fix It utility, I told you so!
- Once the Windows SDK is installed, you have to configure it. Go to Start->All Programs->Microsoft Windows SDK X.Y->Visual Studio Registration->Windows SDK Configuration Tool
- If the config tool yells that you don't have Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 installed... go install it. I installed VS 2008.
- Once all of this is done, on the Matlab prompt, type the line, "mex -setup", and verify that Windows SDK shows as an option and is selected (if you have other compilers - I only got this to work for me with the SDK so I can't comment re:anything else)
- Now, making sure the 'mysql.m' and 'mysql.cpp' is in a folder on the Matlab path, run the compile command exactly as shown in the 'mysql.m' comments. For me, the path to my include and library files was: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\" and then either "bin\" or "lib\" as appropriate for the command.
- For your reference, that full command FOR ME was: mex -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include" -DWIN32 mysql.cpp "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\libmySQL.lib"
- Again, this relies on using whatever version of MySQL that YOU have installed, so if you don't have MySQL 5.6 installed then you need to modify this command to point to the correct location.
- At this point, the file should compile correctly, but you may get an error like several people below have gotten: "Invalid MEX-file : 
  The specified module could not be found" This error is because you have not copied the 'libmysql.dll' file from your \lib\ folder to whichever folder has the mysql.mex file. Once you do this, it should work!
- Finally, for your reference, to be explicit, I have 'mysql.cpp', 'mysql.m', 'mysql.mexw64' all in my root Matlab folder, and then I copied 'libmysql.dll' from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\" to my root Matlab folder.